# Aplicação sem Back-end

Tags: javascript, api, jwt

Estou fazendo uma miniaplicação aqui na empresa, onde ela consome uma API que usa autenticação por JWT (login feito com e-mail e senha)...

Como tudo que fiz até hoje foi com PHP, estou um pouco receoso com questões de segurança pois a aplicação está sendo feita completamente com JavaScript, HTML e CSS.

Obs: Sempre que o token vence, a aplicação apaga o cookie e pede pro usuário entrar com email e senha novamente.

Dúvidas:

- É seguro  que vários usuários fiquem com seus tokens armazenados em cookies?
- As requisições (AJAX) ficam expostas no código, isso é prejudicial?
- O que eu fazia antes no back end com PHP estou fazendo em JS, isso é prejudicial tambem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> É seguro que vários usuários fiquem com seus tokens armazenados em cookies?

É importante observar as recomendações de segurança que envolvem manter identificadores de sessão - e dados similares - em cookies. 
Nesta sessção do MDN você consegue algumas informações sobre o que você pode fazer: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Security
Em resumo, você precisa usar a *flag* httpOnly para que o cookie não seja acessível via JavaScript, o que ajuda a evitar roubo de sessão.

> As requisições (AJAX) ficam expostas no código, isso é prejudicial?

Tudo o que acontece no cliente fica exposto, não é necessariamente prejudicial. Contanto que as APIs que você consomem estejam protegidas por autenticação e autorização, não tem problema. Outra prática fundamental é o uso de https para evitar que outras pessoas possam analisar o tráfego de informações da sua aplicação e roubar a sessão de usuários. Adicionalmente à flag *httponly* citada acima, é importante adicionar a flag *secure*, que define que o cookie só será enviado à aplicação - a API neste caso - caso a conexão seja via https.

> O que eu fazia antes no back end com PHP estou fazendo em JS, isso é prejudicial tambem?

Depende. Suas regras de negócio sempre devem estar no backend, indepentendemente de você colocá-las de alguma forma no front-end também.

Vamos a um exemplo ilustrativo:

Imagine que você tenha uma loja virtual. E que existe uma regra que aplica 20% de desconto sempre que o consumidor comprar mais de 3 itens. Imagine também que esta regra é calculada no front-end e que sua API não verifica, apenas persiste os dados.

Daí um usuário mal-intencionado pode analisar as requests que seu front faz para a API e descobrir como as informações de desconto e preços são enviadas. Daí ele pode fazer uma request para sua API, sem usar a aplicação web que você desenvolveu com js, adicionando 50% de desconto comprando apenas 1 produto. Já que a API não valida, o usuário conseguiu comprar um produto por preço bem abaixo do anunciado de forma indevida.

Toda validação, verificação e aplicação de regras de negócio devem ser feitas na API, você não deve confiar nas informações que a tela envia. 
Algumas regras você consegue colocar no front, como a questão do desconto que eu coloquei acima. Às vezes é útil pois você pode avisar o usuário que se ele comprar mais uma unidade ganha desconto, mas isso não tira a responsabilidade da API fazer a verificação também. O mesmo vale para, por exemplo, validação de formulários, como a obrigatoriedade de campos, se o e-mail é válido, se a idade é um número positivo etc.

Comment: Bom cada requisição é analisada pela API de forma que nem valido com JS, quando dá algum erro ou algum dado está inválido, só repasso a mensagem que a API retorna pro usuário, então não tem problema certo?